# How to write a formula in excel that sums backwards until a value is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write a formula in column D that will sum the values in column C. It needs to start from the cell adjacent to a value in column B, and then keep adding the cells above until there is another value in column B.
So for example it would sum 11, then 15 and stop. Then sum 14 and 26. Then 14.5 would go in the same row as the next value in B etc. There is a different gap between values in column B each time so I can't just tell it to look back by 2 or 3 cells. It could be any number.

I've tried to use a combination of sum, index and match functions, but can't seem to work out a correct syntax

[image: Spreadsheet excerpt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest if you add a grouping column in D, `=IF(B1=1,D1+1,D1)`.
Once you have groups, it becomes a straightforward sumifs: `=IF(B2=1,SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$D$2:$D$10,D2),"")`.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! You just saved me so much manual data entry

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, then one could use the following formula as well using `LAMBDA()` helper functions:*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Fill, DROP(MAP(B1:B10,LAMBDA(x,SUM(B1:x))),-1),
     IF(B2:B10<>"",MAP(_Fill,LAMBDA(x,SUM((x=_Fill)*C2:C10))),""))
```

---

Another alternative using one `LAMBDA()` helper function:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, C2:C10,
     b, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
     c, TOCOL(b/B2:B10,3),
     d, MAP(DROP(VSTACK(1,c+1),-1),c,LAMBDA(e,f,SUM(INDEX(a,SEQUENCE(f-e+1,,e))))),
     IFNA(INDEX(d,MATCH(b,c,)),""))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Two good answers but I will add this one as it seemed a simple way of doing it in one go although not much shorter. So just stack the output values and at each stage:

```
 If column B is blank then blank
   
 Otherwise stack the sum of column C so far minus the sum of the outputs so far.
```

---

```
=LET(dates,A2:A10,
markers,B2:B10,    
values,C2:C10,    
DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(dates)),LAMBDA(a,c,
     VSTACK(a,IF(INDEX(markers,c)="","",SUM(INDEX(values,1):INDEX(values,c))-SUM(a))))),1))
```

[image]